# Error in libc6 while upgrading Debian

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, dist-upgrade

Recently I tried to upgrade my computer from Debian Jessie to Buster (I was not directly upgrading but firstly to Stretch and then to Buster). While upgrading the system to Stretch when I run the `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` it throws this error :

```
dpkg: warning: subprocess old post-removal script was killed by signal (Segmentation fault)
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.24-11+deb9u4_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new post-removal script was killed by signal (Segmentation fault)
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed pre-installation script was killed by signal (Segmentation fault)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.24-11+deb9u4_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I searched almost everywhere for a solution but can't find any.
I have tried running `sudo apt-get -f install` but it says the same error message. Additionally, I can't install any other packages as it says :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using apt-get -f install
```

But doing this doesn't seems to solve the problem. Also I can't remove libc6 because I found somewhere that it is a very important library which even a fool will not remove.
So I can you tell me how do solve this error or an alternate way of upgrading my system. If you could tell me the reason for this error then it would be more helpful for me.

Here's my sources.list file for upgrading to Stretch.

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stretch main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main
```

It's running on an ARMv7 CPU on armhf port.

Forgive me for any grammatical mistakes.

Comment: What kind of ARM CPU do you have? What does `/proc/cpuinfo` contain?

Comment: I have an ARMv7 CPU running on on `armhf` port.